# How to update a table with a list of values at a time?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have

```
update NewLeaderBoards set MonthlyRank=(Select RowNumber() (order by TotalPoints desc) from LeaderBoards)
```

I tried it this way -

```
(Select RowNumber() (order by TotalPoints desc) from LeaderBoards) as NewRanks 
 update NewLeaderBoards set MonthlyRank = NewRanks
```

But it doesnt work for me..Can anyone suggest me how can i perform an update in such a way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the WITH statement and a full CTE:

```
;With Ranks As
    (
    Select PrimaryKeyColumn, Row_Number() Over( Order By TotalPoints Desc ) As Num
    From LeaderBoards
    )
Update NewLeaderBoards
Set MonthlyRank = T2.Num
From NewLeaderBoards As T1
    Join Ranks As T2
        On T2.PrimaryKeyColumn = T1.PrimaryKeyColumn
```

Comment: Yup, it's known as an UPDATE FROM statement, if I recall correctly.